# How to convert datetime strings with a given UTC Offset to an equivalent datetime with a narrower UTC Offset in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, utc

I have a Python Databricks notebook that gets external data that has datetime strings with UTC Offsets between UTC-24:00 and UTC+24:00. An example datetime string is '`2020-06-26T03:05:52+20:00`'. However, I am also using a library(Spark 3.x uses the Java DateTimeFormatter) that only supports UTC Offsets between UTC-18:00 and UTC+18:00. In Spark 3.x, the pyspark function `to_timestamp()` returns `null` for datetimes with a UTC Offset that are outside the +/- 18:00 range.

Example code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("test") \
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g") \
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
  .config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
  .config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
  .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC') \
  .getOrCreate()

columns = ["datetime", "offset"]
data = [
  ("2020-06-26T03:05:52+20:00", "+20:00"),
  ("2020-06-26T03:05:52+02:00", "+2:00"),
]
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

test_df_two = test_df.withColumn(
  'to_ts', F.to_timestamp(F.col("datetime"))
)
test_df_two.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
|datetime                 |offset|to_ts              |
+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
|2020-06-26T03:05:52+20:00|+20:00|null               |
|2020-06-26T03:05:52+02:00|+2:00 |2020-06-26 01:05:52|
+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
```

How can I generically convert such datetime strings to equivalent ones that are within the +/- 18:00 limit my library imposed?

Comment: Can you zero in on the class which is refusing to parse large timezone offsets? It's not clear whether the problem is in Spark or in Java built-in stuff. An example which shows just the behavior of the problematic class would be really great.

Comment: I find that java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse throws an exception when the tz offset is larger than 18 hours, so maybe that's the origin of the problem. This is kind of maddening -- I don't see any statement in ZonedDateTime, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter, or even the Wikipedia page for ISO 8601 (sorry, I wasn't able to locate a normative reference) about the allowable range for the tz offset. In the absence of an official statement about it, it looks as if the implementor(s) of the date parsing stuff made a restrictive assumption about what's "reasonable". Hmm.

Comment: "In 2008, time-zone offsets around the world extended from -12:00 to +14:00. To prevent any problems with that range being extended, yet still provide validation, the range of offsets is restricted to -18:00 to 18:00 inclusive." From : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html

Comment: Huh, well that's nuts. That's like saying "The number of atoms in the universe is somewhat less than 1e82, so the number parser throws an error for anything larger." I'd still like to get a reading on what the spec actually says, or doesn't say, about the offset.

Comment: The behavior change in Spark 3.x is mentioned in the migration guide here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine) under bullet point 12

Comment: I read through the migration guide (not an obvious place to look, to be honest) and then the other stuff referenced there, and I still don't see a definite statement about the allowed values of tz offset. A couple more ideas. (1) Can you get Python to parse it instead of Java? I found some suggestion that `datetime.parse` would allow up to +/- 24 tz offset, although I don't have a reference at hand. (2) As a last resort, maybe implement a parser yourself? Maybe strip off the tz offset and punt to a built-in parser for the date & time and then fix up the offset? Just guessing here. Good luck.